# Mix it up & Wordpress

Tags: theme-development

I'm trying to create a MixItUp of articles. Those articles are in my category "Projet" which as 5 sub-categories. My problem is that I can't sort them
with my sub-cat controls. If someone can explain me why it doesn't work it would be marvellous.
Here is my code :

```
    <div class="col l9 mixitupcontainer pull-l3">

                    <?php 
                            $args = array(
                            'post_type'=>'post',
                            'orderby'=>'asc',
                            'category_name'=> 'projet',
                            );
                            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                            if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>  


                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div class='col l4 vignette-pro mix <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) { echo $category->slug . ' ';} ?>'>
                             <!-- My content -->
</div>
</a>
                      <?php 
                            endwhile;
                            endif;
                       ?>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                 <div class="controls">


                        <form action="#">
                            <h1>Catégories</h1>
                            <p>
                              <label>
                                <input name="group1" type="radio" checked class="control" data-filter="all" />
                                <span>Tous</span>
                              </label>
                            </p>
                            <?php 
                $categories=  get_categories();
                foreach ($categories as $category) 
                    echo '<p>
                              <label>
                                <input name="group1" type="radio" data-filter="'.$category->category_nicename.'">
                                <span>'.$category->cat_name.'</span>
                            </label>
                        </p>';
                ?>

                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Html and jQUERY works, sub-cat are in the `class=""` but it doesn't sort articles.

Sorry for my bad writing skills, and thanks for help !

Comment: Ok I found the problem ! It is solve !

Comment: If you solved the problem then please share your solution, otherwise you're just going to frustrate future users who find this question looking to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Well it is kinda stupid but I forget a "." in the data-filter="" of my controls... The code was good.